# C# - Hide Command Line Window

Tags: command-line, hide

I am starting a bat-File within my code with

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path + ".bat");

How can I hide the command line window of that bat-file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ProcessStartInfo for more control, e.g.

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(path + ".bat"));

psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

Process.Start(psi);
```